# Flutter flexible filtering a list of objects

Tags: flutter

I have a list of objects, lets say students and i would like to filter this list.
I designed a list of 3 dropdownmenus, 1. towns, 2. gender, 3. age.

My target is to filter in order(1.town 2.gender and 3.age) or filter only gender.

Ive tried the following:

```
List<Students> studentsFiltered = [];
List<Students> allStudents = [];

 studentsFiltered = allStudents.where((student) => student.town == town).where((student) => student.gender == gender).where((student) => student.age == age).toList();
```

The result i get seems to be an "and" logic filtering but i need a flexible "or" way but how can i do this?

If you need more information, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this?

```
studentsFiltered = allStudents.where((student) => student.town == town || student.gender == gender || student.age == age).toList();
```

Comment: Yeah i guess, didn`t knew that this syntax is possible, i gonna try it! Thank you!

Comment: It works a bit better, bit it mixes genders and towns in the result. I tried && but the i can`t select only gender or only town. Is there maybe a better aproach with hive iam also using?